# Symfony2 custom validation constrain usage in form builder

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I tried creating custom validation rule to use when building form following: [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Here's what I'v came to:

```
namespace Path\ToBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class NotValidSearch extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Search string is invalid format.';
}



namespace Salda\ClientControlBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;


class ContainsNotValidSearchValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (count(explode(' ', $value)) !== 3) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message);
        }
    }
}
```

and then tried using it inside form builder class:

```
use Path\ToBundle\Validator\Constraints\NotValidSearch;

$builder->add('search', 'search', array(
    'label' => 'Predecessor',
    'required' => false,
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => new NotValidSearch(array(
        'message' => 'invalid message ph'
    ))
));
```

But when I am submiting the form it throws error:
Fatal error: Class 'Path\ToBundle\Validator\Constraints\NotValidSearchValidator' not found in /path/to/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Validator/ConstraintValidatorFactory.php on line 71

My question is: have I misunderstood how to use custom validators or I am just missing something or doing it wrong? Because I wan't to use it in when building the form since I need to use it on non mapped property.
And is this an appropriate way of doing this?, or maybe there's other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the base `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint` class there is the validatedBy method

```
public function validatedBy()
{
    return get_class($this).'Validator';
}
```

Meaning that your class `NotValidSearch` would be validated by `NotValidSearchValidator` rather than your chosen `ContainsNotValidSearchValidator`.

You will either need to change the name of your validator to `NotValidSearchValidator` or change the validatedBy to the correct name of your validator.